# React router doesn't rerender the view just updates the URL on custom local domain

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So I'm using React Router v4 on my universal application.

I use StaticRouter for SSR and regular Router for browser.
I create history with browserHistory and pass it over to the router.

So, when I run the application through local port (localhost:8081) the `react-router-dom` `<Link>` elements works fine.

The problem is when I try to access the page via a custom local domain which is governed by nginx. I have a reverse proxy there and the redirect itself works fine - when I access a homepage or any other `/page`, it renders the page just fine.

The problem is that neither the `<Link>` component and `.push` functions don't work. They just update the URL but the view isn't re-rendering.

I've read about update blocking, but I don't have any PureComponents that could block the render. Also, it's mindboggling because it seems to work fine when running on localhost:8081.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you for all the answers

Comment: do you use any `connect`s from react-router?

Comment: Yes I do, I've tried replacing Router with StoreProvider but that didn't seem to have any impact. Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using passing `{ pure: false }` as 4th argument to you `connect`s to see if this makes any change. See [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux).